# When should I use a BaseActivity?

Tags: android, performance

I have recently discovered the method of using a `BaseActivity` for items common throughout particular activities.

I want a Navigation Drawer throughout multiple activities and thought this would be a good time to have a go at it. Is it worth it for just a Navigation Drawer and maybe a few other things? Does it effect performance much, either negitavely or positively? Are there any other pros/cons I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a base activity only for the classes that would benifit from that base activity. For example, in one of my applications, each activity has a header, footer, and body. It also needs to have access to heart rate devices. So, for I created a base activity that handles the layout of the header, footer, and heart rate service. I also have the base activity implement my interface created for the heart rate service.

Now, there are some other activities that have to connect to BLE Machines, so I created a base class for those that extends the base class that I created for all the activities.

If to much inheritance occurs, the code can be hard to follow and maintain. Also, changing the code can be cumbersome since it would be harder to remove features from deeply embedded children.

The plus side is the lack of duplicated code and easier maintenance for functions that are used universally.

Comment: also remember that Google states to keep inheritance at a minimum, only if you benefit greatly from it - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html